# Will ubuntu be able to connect to my wifi on my asus laptop without installing drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, asus

**Hi**, 
I am looking in to installing ubuntu on my old asus laptop from somewhere around 2011.

And while i was doing some resurce I remembered that when i bought my computer I don't remember if it came with some drivers discs or not and i was wondering if i need network drivers for connecting to wifi *(i got ethernet cords as well)* or if it is just to scan for my wifi, chose wifi and login with my routers password and then just install *(i know that the install does not requre internet but it is prutty important to have after the installation)*.

Comment: It depends on the exact wireless device; some will and some won't. Can you identify the wireless device? The more details, the better we can judge. Almost every ethernet device is covered.

Comment: Ubuntu comes with `wifi` abilities provided your hard is there, which in your case it is. So just install and it should work.